# using sklearn class weight to increase number of positive guesses in extremely unbalanced data set?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, class-imbalance, weighted-data

Hi I have a poorly correlated and unbalanced data set I have to work with. The set is 2 classes, 0 has 96,000 values and 1 has about 200. When I run random forest or other methods I get an output like:

```
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      1.00      1.00     38300
          1       1.00      0.01      0.02        90

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
```

Precision is very high but it only classified one row as positive?

I tried using {class_weight = 'balanced'} in the random forest parameters and it provides:

```
   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
   macro avg       1.00      0.51      0.51     38390
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
```

But still not many positive guesses? Should I look into oversampling?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to compute [class weights](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) and assign these values to model via weight classes function. One more reminder about weights; probably major classes weight will be less than 1 so you need to round it to 1 otherwise model won't learn major class this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the `Loss function` of the algorithm, It will be very helpful. There are many useful metrics which were introduced for evaluating the performance of classification methods for imbalanced data-sets. Some of them are **[Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)**, **[CEN](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.708.1668&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**, **[MCEN](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-94120-2_8)**, **[MCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)**, and **[DP](https://eva.fing.edu.uy/pluginfile.php/69453/mod_resource/content/1/7633-10048-1-PB.pdf)**.

If you use python, **[PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm)** module can help you to find out these metrics.

Here is a simple code to get the recommended parameters from this module:

```
>>> from pycm import *

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(matrix={"Class1": {"Class1": 1, "Class2":2}, "Class2": {"Class1": 0, "Class2": 5}})  

>>> print(cm.recommended_list)
["Kappa", "SOA1(Landis & Koch)", "SOA2(Fleiss)", "SOA3(Altman)", "SOA4(Cicchetti)", "CEN", "MCEN", "MCC", "J", "Overall J", "Overall MCC", "Overall CEN", "Overall MCEN", "AUC", "AUCI", "G", "DP", "DPI", "GI"]
```

After that, each of these parameters you want to use as the loss function can be used as follows:

```
>>> y_pred = model.predict      #the prediction of the implemented model

>>> y_actu = data.target        #data labels

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred)

>>> loss = cm.Kappa             #or any other parameter (Example: cm.SOA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do some resampling to your data in order to create a balanced training set for the training your classification model. This can be done in python with SMOTE - you can find some implementation example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/qianchao/smote-with-imbalance-data).

Also, have a look to [this question and answers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40815/exceptionally-high-accuracy-with-random-forest-is-it-possible/40854#40854), discussing ways to train and validate classification models from unbalanced datasets, eliminating the bias as much as possible.